# How these url rest parameters are being generated

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working with a site where from I can download publicly free data based on rest parameter in url as below.

1. Url for Online DCR[type of receipt for land mutation fee payment] No:
   http://XXX/pages/doc?data=21192
2. Url for khatian[type of document to ensure right and title of land]: https://XXX/qr-vk/b59e7
3. Url for dakhila[type of receipt for payment of land tax]:
   https://YYYY/MVBDSzI4UTYzdUsydFJLZGJwT0x2

Now my question is how to understand the code `21192` , `b59e78` and `MVBDSzI4UTYzdUsydFJLZGJwT0x2Z9` - though I am interested more in the first 7 and 8 digit code i.e. `21192` and `b59e78`.

I am planning to collect all the data from the site using python requests module. Now I am using brute force get method by all the permutation of lowercase letter and number with 7 and 8 digit length but it takes million of requests which is time consuming and less effective. So I need to find a way to decode the 7 and 8 digit codes.

Brute-force code I am using now-

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import string
import itertools
import PyPDF2
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
import random


asciiletters =list(string.ascii_letters)
lowercases =list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:]
numbers = list(map(str,list(range(0,10))))[:]


for nmbr in numbers:
    #numbers = [n for n in numbers if nmbr!=n]
    codes_chunk_to_write = []
    prmlist = numbers+lowercases
    random.shuffle(prmlist)
    idlist = itertools.permutations(prmlist,6)
    #counter = 0
    #lenght_of_permutation = sum(1 for ignore in idlist)
    
    for id_ in idlist:
        code = 'b'+nmbr+''.join(id_)       
        #print(code)
    
        #code = 'b59e78'
        url = 'https://XXX/qr-vk/'+code
        pdfname = code+'.pdf'
        response = requests.get(url)
        
        if "@@@@@@" in response.text:
            pdf_response = requests.get('https://XXX/qr-print/'+code)
            with open(pdfname, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(pdf_response.content)
            
        print(f"Completed {code}")
```

---

Unfortunately, all answers posted here tell, at least in a way, that these codes[21192,b59e78] are useless in terms of response got from the link. All codes are just a mere random unique identifier. It not feasible to track response from the link with respective code and so so. But from the first I always told there is a link between the response content and the code.

What I Have got.

---

1. Url http://XXX/pages/doc?data=21192 returns
   pdf contains a value `৪৭০৬` which is English equivalent to
   `4706167`. Decimal value of hex `21192` is `347061`. Just prepended
   by a single digit `3` which is division code.
2. Url https://XXX/qr-vk/b59e7 returns pdf
   contains a value `৪৭০৬১` which is English equivalent to
   `47061`. Decimal value of hex `b59e7` is `304706`. Just
   prepended by a double digit `30` and appended by a single digit `1`
   which I am searching for.

I lingered to post this update thinking I might come up with a full answer later since `21192` has been fully understood only.
Hopefully, I think there are more things to observe which demands more time, for noob like me at least.

Comment: Completely unsure what you are trying to scrape here. First links returns a PDF, second and third link are completely in random language I don't understand at all...

Comment: All three links are inter connected land ownerships related documents of a single person in bengali language. I have attached the code already to explain what i am want to scrape.But the problem is i do not understand the alphanumeric code part of the requested urls.I need to understand how these codes are generated, i suspect that those code are linked to the respose got from respective url.

Comment: From which URL are you redirected to https://mutation.land.gov.bd/qr-vk/b59e78a7 ?

Comment: From nothing it is a link got using QR code scan.

Comment: This website runs on nginx webserver, can't find any sitemap.xml or robots.txt...

Comment: Normally these types of codes are generated at random, for example the 8 characters with ```shortId = RandomStringUtils.random(8, "0123456789abcdef"); ``` or perhaps with ```x = uuid4() str(x)[:8]```. Who knows, its decided server based and linked to information that only shows on your specific request.

Comment: Code generation must not be at random. Since it may generate same code for two different land documents which is absurd.

Comment: I think the code has any type of link between repoonse content and the code.

Comment: So you generate a random code, and then check if it is unique compared to your database, if not add it? In addition chance for random with 8 characters possibility of 37 to power of 8 being 4 quadrillion.

Comment: 4 quadrillion- that's the brute-force method I am using now. I am here to get new solution! I think there must be something to be reverse-engineered.

Comment: How did you find the record `21192f7` from this site https://mutation.land.gov.bd

Comment: Were you able to resolve this @SIslam ?

Comment: @Charchit not yet by  a noob like me as stated in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

b59e78a7 is hex for 3047061671 so you just iterate up to 5B or so and hex the numbers

Comment: I know that's a hex, in fact. Does this answer answer my problem at all? This answer tells to use brute-force method which I posted earlier in my question before this answer is posted. I need to avoid those types brute-force approach needs quadrillions of requests as discussed both in the question itself and in the comments section of the question too!!!

Comment: In fact I do not know what do you mean by this answer even this answer is not qualified for comment since there exits some type of comment in the comment section of the question addressing brute-force approach.

Comment: I don't know where you get quadrillions from, 0xffffffff is 4.2 billion

Comment: How have you deduced that I am here to get answer suggests me making billions of requests to achieve the goal while i am opposed to this type of brute-force method as mentioned in the question itself and comment.

Comment: I agree that it would be pretty obnoxious, but this is the best way to do it.

Comment: `but this is the best way` among brute-force approaches which I did not wanted obviously, at least from here.

Comment: If you're looking for a scifi / fantasy based approach you're probably on the wrong forum.